# freertos subpriority of xSemaphoreTake() within same priority tasks

Tags: task, mutex, freertos

I have three tasks  with same priority.

```
Task A 
mutextake()
//critical code
mutexgive()

Task B 
mutextake()
//critical code
mutexgive()

Task C 
mutextake()
//critical code
mutexgive()
```

Each of them run critical code guarded by a mutex. However I would like to set a "subpriority" to who would take the mutex in the event that two of the tasks are blocking waiting for the mutex. I dont want to set the tasks with different priorities as this will cause complications within the design of other tasks. Is this a feature with freertos to set a "subpriority" for a task to grab a mutex before another of the same priority?

Answer (score 1):

In a word "no".  FreeRTOS inter-task communication objects (https://www.freertos.org/Inter-Task-Communication.html) have lists of tasks waiting to send and lists of tasks waiting to receive (taking a mutex being a receive).  The task in the list that succeeds when the operation can complete is the task with the highest priority - or if the tasks have equal priority - the task that has been waiting the longest.